# Why is my Azure Worker Role Restarting?

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services

I feel like I'm missing some basic piece of understanding on cloud services or asyncs (or both) so I apologize if this is elementary. However, despite spending several hours researching over the past couple months I have yet to find an article or other resource that gave me an "Aha!" moment.

I have an Azure Classic Cloud Service that runs a single worker role. As a startup task, it checks for Chrome in a directory and installs it if it's missing. On my dev machine, I do not have Chrome in that location so every debug session I get the "Grant Permission to Install Chrome" dialogue, as expected.

I found, while debugging locally, that if I pause on a breakpoint (or while stepping through) longer than 90 seconds, I will again get the "Install Chrome" dialogue and VS will alert me that I'm only debugging one of several threads.

If there's any code I need to post to shed light on this, I'll be happy to (but I couldn't determine what might be relevant). What on earth is going on, and do I have any control over when this "restart" or "new thread trigger" happens?

Comment: I would suggest you check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-troubleshoot-common-issues-which-cause-roles-recycle and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-troubleshoot-deployment-problems incase if you haven't checked earlier and see if that helps.

Comment: @Ashok thank you! Sadly I've already reviewed these at length and they are geared more towards bigger, application-breaking problem, not anything like I'm experiencing.